# Python: sort list based on value present in dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Consider list `x = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5]` they are grouped in a manner where

```
obj1.freq = obj2.freq = frequency1 
and 
obj3.freq = obj4.freq = obj5.freq = frequency2
```

and I have a dict

```
y = {obj1 : 40, obj2 :50, obj3:60, obj4:10, obj5:70, obj6:30, obj7:20}
```

I have to SORT list x by considering obj of same frequency and sort based on the values of the obj present in dict and my final result should be

```
x = [obj2,obj1, obj5,obj3,obj4]
```

1st consider `obj1` and `obj2` only because they belong to same frequency and sort looking into their values in `dict y`. `obj2` value is `50` and `obj1` value is `40`.

so list `x` now will be sorted such that its 1st element will be `obj2` followed by `obj1`

and i have to do the same for next set of objects belonging to same frequency and sort based on the value present in dict y 
How do i do it ?

Comment: Are these grouping on `frequency` defined somewhere explicitly or you have these objects in the same list and the objs having same frequency are always put together?

Comment: the objs having same frequency are always put together

Comment: please post in a self-contained proper example on how to initialize these objects. Now every single person attempting to answer your question needs to spend *more* time than it took for you to write this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses the tuple `(frequency, value-in-y)` as the sort key; the list is sorted in reverse order, so that the highest frequency comes first (was not specified in the question, if this is wrong, you can use `-i.freq` there); objects having frequencies get sorted by the second item in the tuple (the value from dictionary `y`, if any, or 0:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, name, freq):
        self.freq = freq
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


obj1 = Obj('obj1',42)
obj2 = Obj('obj2',42)
obj3 = Obj('obj3',6)
obj4 = Obj('obj4',6)
obj5 = Obj('obj5',6)
obj6 = Obj('obj6',332)
obj7 = Obj('obj7',123)


x = [obj2, obj1, obj5, obj3, obj4]
y = {obj1:40, obj2:50, obj3:60, obj4:10, obj5:70, obj6:30, obj7:20}

print(sorted(x, key=lambda i: (i.freq, y.get(i, 0)), reverse=True))
```

Prints

```
[obj2, obj1, obj5, obj3, obj4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess you can do it in this way:

```
x = [obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5]
y = {obj1 : 40, obj2 :50, obj3:60, obj4:10, obj5:70, obj6:30, obj7:20}

sorted_list=sorted(lambda e: (e.freq, 0-y[e]), x)
```

Note, you need `0-y[e]` if you want order from bigger values to smaller. 
Normally it can be reached by `reverse=True`, but in our case it will affect sorting by frequency as well